# I want to get an export of all storage accounts, where in the output it shows its Sku.Name, but am having trouble calling it

Tags: powershell, azure-storage-account

The following is what I have so far:

```
$result=@()
$storageaccounts= Get-AzStorageAccount

foreach($storageaccount in $storageaccounts){
    
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        $Name= $storageaccount.ResourceGroupName
        $Location= $storageaccount.Location
        $Kind= $storageaccount.Kind
        $Replication= $storageaccount.sku.Name
    }

    $result += $obj
} 

$result | Export-Csv -Path "insert path"
```

Comment: "having trouble calling it" doesn't mean anything. Please explain the issue, including error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just creating your objects using variables that were not defined.

Also, I believe the property is `SkuName` not `Sku.Name`.

When you're not sure what properties your object has, you can use `Get-Member`:

```
$storageaccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
$storageaccounts | Get-Member
```

```
$storageaccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount

$result = foreach($storageaccount in $storageaccounts)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $storageaccount.ResourceGroupName
        Location = $storageaccount.Location
        Kind = $storageaccount.Kind
        Replication = $storageaccount.SkuName
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path "insert path"
```

Comment: This works, except I used Sku.Name to get the replication type (the property "Sku" has a child property "Name"). Thanks!

Comment: @Jawaria Im happy to help :) I was looking at [this picture](https://i0.wp.com/www.checkyourlogs.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/image-14.png) and didnt see the `Sku` property hence why I changed it. My bad